# On the characterization of Prüfer rings

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Aside form Griffin's article (1969) and Butts and Smith (1967), can someone recommend me a book or another article on the equivalent definitions of Prüfer rings with zero-divisors, one that may have another approach or different proofs? A book would help a lot, it may be easier to digest.

Comment: You might look at the book Multiplicative Theory of Ideals by Larsen and McCarthy from 1971.  Chapter X introduces valuation pairs and Prüfer rings with zero divisors.

Answer (score 0):

There is the book of Max D. Larsen, Paul J. McCarthy, "Multiplicative Theory of Ideals" (1971). Chapter 10 is about Prüfer rings with zero-divisors.